# error when trying to import a font file in python/ pygame

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I'm trying to import a font file like this:

```
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('/home/user/pygame/lib/freesansbold.ttf', 18)
```

but then I get this error:

```
OSError: unable to read font file '/home/user/pygame/lib/freesansbold.ttf'
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: did you check for the permissions?

Comment: how do I check them?

Comment: ls -l <that file> check If it has read permission. 'r' indicates read permission

Comment: no permission, how do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it to be generally good practice to create a directory inside of your project direct, perhaps called "fonts", and load the font directly from that directory.

This is particularly useful if frequently switching between operating systems, or generally useful to promote capability to switch between operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, following a pdf that may be a little dated.

Try this,

```
pygame.font.SysFont(freesansbold.ttf', 18)
```